# Shell file execution on crontab is not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

When I try the command `sudo /bin/sh /var/www/domain.com/file_sync.sh` in the terminal, It is getting executed successfully without any errors. But when I try to execute the same command from crontab it is not working and I am not any output/errors in the log. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 14,04 is long past EOL and and off topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

My first question to you is whose crontab is this? Is it yours (the user) or the root user's?
I noticed that you have the command exactly as you ran it in the console, implying that you want it run with root privilege. May I suggest that you change the 'sudo' to 'root' in the crontab entry as that will ensure that the command is run by root user.
Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all the crontab is meant for the root user. I have added root instead of sudo in the crontab as per your suggestion. Now I am getting this error in the log `/bin/sh: 1: root: not found`

Comment: Ah ok, cool. If this is the root crontab then there is no need to have 'sudo' or 'root' in there as it is automatically run by root.

Comment: I've tried without root/sudo still it is the same I am not getting the file executed.

Comment: One thing I am sure of is that the crontab is working and I can see the crontab execution log in `syslog`

Comment: Have you removed the '/bin/sh' bit as well?

Comment: Yes, I've removed and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Any luck? If it now works, what changed?

Answer (score 0):

delete the root, sudo and /bin/sh items in the command line.

edit file_sync.sh and add the first line "#!/bin/sh" (without the quotes)

check the /bin/sh points to an executable, and the file_sync.sh has the executable bit set.